# Почему в браузере не отображается стандартный интерфейса django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Установил DRF, создал views, models, serializers, url. Добавил в INSTALLED_APPS+='rest_framework'. Но когда посылаю get запрос то в браузере вижу вернувшийся респонс в виде json и никаких признаков наличия стандартного шаблона DRF.

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers
from users import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/v1/', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),]
```

Answer (score 0):

В settings.py в дефолтных настройках DRF было прописано

```
'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
],
```

Убрал ее и все заработало.